# How can i properly display the lifetimes of people in a chart

Tags: excel

I can make the  chart work for persons who are born after 0. However people before  b.c for example -500 the age  chart which is a stacked column chart starts at 0 and not after the value of when the person was born.

[For positive year times it works](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5mAln.png)

[Here are the rows and columns that are used](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VkR7N.png)

[I have hidden the born chart so it only shows when and how long a person lived](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UkYCX.png)

how can I fix the problem that people born before 0 don't have their lifetime properly shown?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you might have also people born BC and dead AC, you'll need 3 segments. Let's say that the top left cell of your table is cell A1 (therefore Nietzsche name is in cell A2), your segments will use these formulas:

---

```
=IF(B2>0,B2,IF(C2<0,C2,0))
```

This will return either:

- the birth year of those born AC
- the death year of those dead BC
- zero

This segment needs no filling (it must be invisible).

---

```
=CHOOSE(1+1*(B2>0)*(C2>0)+2*(B2<0)*(C2<0),0,C2-B2,B2-C2)
```

This will return either:

- the age of death for those born AC
- the negative of the age of death for those dead BC
- zero

This segment has to be colored.

---

```
=IF((B2>0)*(C2>0)+(B2<0)*(C2<0),0,C2)
```

This will return either:

- the year of death of those born BC and dead AC
- zero

This segment has to be colored.

---

---

*Note: since there is no year 0, the graph will essentially be "wrong" at the intersection of the two axis at zero.*